# Acs712 current sensor ic interfacing with ade7858(energy metering ic)

Tags: current, sensor, analog, converter, interface

I am trying to interface Acs712 current sensor IC with an energy metering Ic(Ade7858),there are two problems am currently facing.

1) The energy metering Ic takes in bipolar input (± 0.5 V) which is designed to use current transformer but the output from Acs712 is uni-polar which is (0-5v).

[image]

2)I tried using the schematic above to convert uni-polar (0-5v)  to bipolar(± 0.5 V)  which gives a single ended output but the inputs for the Ade7878(energy metering IC) is differential input as shown in the below diagram from datasheet.

[image]

kindly suggest me if I should go with a single ended to differential converter if am not wrong or is there a better cost effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

The ACS output is centred upon Vcc/2

You could generate a Vcc/2 with a voltage divider and a buffer opamp and feed that into the differential input to satisfy the input requirement

Comment: sorry i still don't follow can you please explain.